# How to Compare to Lists in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I want to *compare / filter* my mobile contact list with the list form firebase users collection.
Both lists items contains **number** field and i want to show the firebase users containing the same number from contact list.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final contactListProvider = Provider.of<ContactProvider>(context);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: Custom_appbar(
      title: 'Trusted Contacts',
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: contactListProvider.loadingcontact
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : StreamBuilder<List<UserModel>?>(
                stream: MyFirebaseDB().userdata(),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  final usersFirebase = snapshot.data;

                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: usersFirebase!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        var fireuser = usersFirebase[index];
                        var contact = contactListProvider.usercontactlist[index];

                        return Text(fireuser.userNumber.toString());

                   
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text('something wrong');
                  }
                },
              ), 
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupListsBy()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html) from the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) to map one of the lists by number.

Then use [`Iterable.where()`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) to scan the second list for numbers which exist in the map.

For example:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Contact {
  final String name;
  final String number;
  Contact(this.name, this.number);
  @override String toString() => '$name ($number)';
}

List<Contact> findCommonNumbers(List<Contact> list1, List<Contact> list2) {
  var map = list1.groupListsBy((e) => e.number);
  return list2.where((e) => map.containsKey(e.number)).toList();
}

main() {
  var contacts = [
    Contact('Adam', '12345'),
    Contact('Bob', '77889'),
    Contact('Charlie', '33221'),
  ];
  var fromDatabase = [
    Contact('April', '45678'),
    Contact('Bobby', '77889'),
    Contact('Chris', '76543'),
  ];
  print(findCommonNumbers(contacts, fromDatabase));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[Bobby (77889)]
```